# Working on multilevel list (2)

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list like:

```
li = ['0', ['1', '2'], ['3', ['4', '5'], '6', ['7'], '8'], '9']
```

How can I implement a function that yields tuples in the form of `(elem, indexes)`:

- `elem` is the element
- `indexes` is the indexes needed to reach to that elem.

Example:

```
>>> for x in my_func(li):
    print x
('0', [0])
('1', [1, 0])
('2', [1, 1])
('3', [2, 0])
('4', [2, 1, 0])
('5', [2, 1, 1])
('6', [2, 2])
('7', [2, 3, 0])
('8', [2, 4])
('9', [3])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a nested version

```
li = ['0', ['1', '2'], ['3', ['4', '5'], '6', ['7'], '8'], '9']
def to_int(lst, path=[]):
    for i, j in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(j, list):
            yield list(to_int(j, path+[i]))
        else:
            yield int(j), path+[i]

print(list(to_int(li)))
```

And a  flattened version (Python3.3+)

```
li = ['0', ['1', '2'], ['3', ['4', '5'], '6', ['7'], '8'], '9']
def to_int(lst, path=[]):
    for i, j in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(j, list):
            yield from to_int(j, path+[i])
        else:
            yield int(j), path+[i]

for item in to_int(li):
    print (item)
```

If you can't use `yield from`(< Python3.3), you have to write it this cumbersome way

```
li = ['0', ['1', '2'], ['3', ['4', '5'], '6', ['7'], '8'], '9']
def to_int(lst, path=[]):
    for i, j in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(j, list):
            for item in to_int(j, path+[i]): yield item
        else:
            yield int(j), path+[i]

for item in to_int(li):
    print (item)
```

Note, it's *usually* a bad idea to have an empty list as a default parameter, but here we are careful not to mutate it, so it's ok.

Comment: +1 for the empty list warning... Been there, and it baked my cookie.

Answer (score 1):

```
def nextedindex(lst, indice=tuple()):
    for index, data in enumerate(lst):
        if isinstance(data, collections.Sequence):
            for next in nestedindex(data, indice + (index,)): yield next
        else:
            yield indice + (index,), data
```

Comment: `str` are instances of `collections.Sequence` too!

Comment: `(,)` isn't how you write an empty tuple

Comment: Your function name is mispelled

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursive version.

This one loops through each level of the list recursively, keeping track of the index path to reach the current loop in `currentIndex`.

```
def indexRecursive(alist, currentIndex, tuples):
    i = 0
    for item in alist:
        if type(item) != list:
           tuples.append((item, currentIndex + [i]))
        else:
            indexRecursive(alist[i], currentIndex + [i], tuples)
        i += 1

li = ['0', ['1', '2'], ['3', ['4', '5'], '6', ['7'], '8'], '9']
tuplesList = []
indexRecursive(li, [], tuplesList)
print tuplesList
```

Comment: Although this does work, generators are more "pythonic" (see gnibbler's answer).